# Wraparound Transaction ID

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-9.6

Once the `txid` has passed the the `xmin`/`xmax` 32 bit limit, and assuming you've not suffered any issues with wraparound because you've been correctly maintaining your tables (plenty of vacuums, vacuum freeze, etc.), what happens to the `txid`?  Does it just continue to increment? If so, how do `xmin` and `xmax` store it?

Answer (score 0):

It wraps around to FirstNormalTransactionId (which is 3), rather than to zero.  And then it continues to increment and be stored into xmin and xmax like normal.